# data fetched from redux store didn't show in component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have been creating a todo app with Django backend and react Frontend using REACT API. The action is successfully dispatched and data fetched successfully, but in the `RenderTodo` Component the data has not appeared. Below are the attached files.
Definitely, there's just small thing I'm missing but can't get it!
I'm somewhat new to this thing so, need help.
Is it anything like declaring an empty state in `TodoComponent.js`?
I have also attached the rendered form in the browser at last.

Along with below data I have now put it on GitHub [here](https://github.com/LaxmanChoudhary/django-react-todo).

Directory Structure is

[image: directory structure]

Files:
*configureStore.js*

```js
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import logger from 'redux-logger';

import { Todos } from './reducers/todo';

export const ConfigureStore =() => {
    const store = createStore(
        combineReducers({
            todos: Todos,
        }),
        composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk, logger))
    );
    return store;
}
```

*ActionCreators.js*

```js
import * as ActionTypes from './ActionTypes';
import { baseUrl } from './baseUrl';
import axios from 'axios';

//GET_TODOS
export const getTodos = () => (dispatch) => {
    axios
        .get('api/todo/')
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: ActionTypes.GET_TODOS,
                payload: res.data
            });
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

*todo.js*

```js
import * as ActionTypes from '../ActionTypes';

export const initialState = {
    todos: []
}

export const Todos = (state=initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.GET_TODOS:
            return {
                ...state,
                todos: action.payload
            };

        default:
            return state;
    }

};
```

*App.js*

```js
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";

//used for providing store to all child components
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

import Todo from "./components/TodoComponent";
import { ConfigureStore } from "./redux/configureStore";

const store = ConfigureStore();

export class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Fragment>
                    <Todo />
                </Fragment>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

*TodoComponent.js*

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { getTodos } from "../redux/ActionCreators";
import RenderTodo from "./RenderTodoComponent";

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    todos: state.todos.todos,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    getTodos: () => {
        dispatch(getTodos());
    },
});

class Todo extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getTodos();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Main">
                <h1>Todos</h1>
                <RenderTodo todos={this.props.todos} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Todo);
```

*RenderComponent.js*

```js
import React from "react";

export default function RenderTodo(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            {console.log("second component")}
            <table className="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Text</th>
                        <th>Completed</th>
                        <th>Created_at</th>
                        <th />
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {props.todos.map((todo) => {
                        <tr key={todo.id}>
                            <td>{todo.id}</td>
                            <td>{todo.text}</td>
                            <td>{todo.created_at}</td>
                            <td>{todo.completed}</td>
                            <td>
                                <button className="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>;
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**browser**
console printing **second component** is a debugging statement showing the rendering of the second component and then the first components' componentDidMount is called.
[image]

**EDIT:** Added redux-dev tools -images
I have attached action, state and diff, hope this helps in troubleshooting. Everything seems fine here
[image: devtools action]

[image: devtools state]

[image: devtools diff]

Comment: Where do you call _RenderTodo_ from? As far as I see, you exported it but you are not importing _RenderComponent.js_ from anywhere?

Comment: I don't see mapStateToProp or useSelector anywhere, only the same reducer posted 3 times. Did you check redux dev tools, did you notice todos are in `state.todos.todos`?

Comment: @Gurcan sorry for the copy-paste mistakes, I mistakenly pasted another file, but it's sorted now. RenderComponent is used in `TodoComponent.js`

Comment: @HMR that was mistake from my side, i have edited it. So please you can have a look at it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't **RETURN**ing anything from `props.todos.map`

Replace the `{` and `}` with `(` and `)` to return the JSX.

```js
                   {props.todos.map((todo) => ( // this was previously a {
                        <tr key={todo.id}>
                            <td>{todo.id}</td>
                            <td>{todo.text}</td>
                            <td>{todo.created_at}</td>
                            <td>{todo.completed}</td>
                            <td>
                                <button className="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}
```

Comment: well, that was the thing, thanks for your time... I definitely knew I was doing something foolish.